# What's the easiest way to assign different numbers to a set of data in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file that has approximately 7000 rows and 50 columns. What I want to do is create a new column that has the name 'Sample Number', and I would like to assign numbers to corresponding data. For example, the rows between 500-1500 correspond to sample 1, 1500-2500 correspond to sample 2, and so on. Right now,  the code that I have has the ability to create a new column and assign numbers, but what I want is to ask the user what range of data corresponds to which sample, and afterward, the program will assign the numbers to the specific rows. Now, it assigns 1 to every row. I have attached a link to the image,  Here is the code I have now

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = r"C:/Users/barış/Desktop/test2.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/barış/Desktop/test2.xlsx")

df['Sample Number'] = "1"
df.head(5)
df.to_excel("C:/Users/barış/Desktop/test2.xlsx") #Write DateFrame back as Excel file
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R83b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. It would be easier if you could save the excel file as a CSV file

That way you can loop through each row and using if statements you can add the data you need depending on the row.

However, I don't know if that's the easiest method or not but it's fairly straightforward especially using CSV format.